# how to left justify text in quote environment with the rest of the text in justified format

Tags: horizontal-alignment, quoting

I need to left justify text in `quote` environment. The rest of the text is justified to both margins.

I just need to raggedright the text inside the quote environment.

I'm using this

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\quote}{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin 0.5in \rightmargin 0}{}{}
```

to change the margins.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The patch you need is the following:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\raggedright}
```

so that each time a `quote` environment starts, the text is typeset ragged right.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\raggedright}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{quote}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the `quoting` environment, which is easily customisable:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{erewhon} %
 \usepackage{quoting} %
\usepackage{lipsum}
\quotingsetup{font={itshape, raggedright, noindent}, leftmargin=0.5in, rightmargin=0in, begintext=‘, endtext=’}

 \begin{document}

 \lipsum[2]
\begin{quoting}
Sed feugiat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
 montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut pellentesque augue sed urna.
 Vestibulum diam eros, fringilla et, consectetuer eu, nonummy id,
 sapien. Nullam at lectus. In sagittis ultrices mauris. Curabitur
 malesuada erat sit amet massa. Fusce blandit. Aliquam erat volutpat.
 Aliquam euismod. Aenean vel lectus. Nunc imperdiet justo nec dolor.
\end{quoting}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Miktex return this error just starting the compilation:

Command \quoting already defined. 
Leaders not followed by proper glue...

i don't know, becouse i don´t use nor import this package before nor other file in the document...

Comment: Do you use a `\quoting` command somewhere else in your document? Can you compile this very code?

Comment: Yes, i can compile this code...

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable code reproducing the problem? I suspect a conflict with another package.

Comment: Yes, i can compile this code...

But i can't compile my code. Even i haven't any \quoting command in my document... Not even \quote command. In no one of the tex files... not even in the cls file... (a class provided by my university).

Very strange..

Comment: Could you post a minimal code (and a link to your university class)?

Comment: Bernard, the problem is that i have a cls file, and various tex files, the document base one and the chapters...
I don,t know how to sharre, what  to share...

Comment: Well, try posting a copy of you master file (which should be rather short, I suppose), replacing the various `\include`s by, say, `\chapter{Some title}`. Tehe most important point is knowing *which packages* you load, and maybe what macros you define.